# How to export or view audio file references in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a an interactive PDF file that is over 90+ pages long. Each page is a map with city names that contains a Spanish pronunciation of that city in a .wav file. I'd say there are about 10-15 audio files for each map which comes out to 1000+ audio files. Is there a way to extract/export a list of the sound file names associated with each map? I tried to save the PDF to an HTML file, but it only exported images and text, and because the audio files were embedded in the PDF, the file names did not carry over to the HTML file. Any other ideas?

I need to see what audio file goes with what map/page.